# Prop `className` did not match. Server.... react js next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

hello i wanted to change the background dynamically and henced i used this method , this is working fine but this error is showing, which lets me unsatisfied ...however i am using dynamic color but when i hardcode a color it does not show me this error. again code is working as i expected but showing error

```
function theme() {
const ls = require('local-storage');
const [dark, setdark] = useState(false);

function set(params) {
    setdark((dark) => !dark);
    if (dark) {
        console.log('disabled');
        ls.set('color', 'white');
    } else {
        console.log('enabled');
        ls.set('color', '#141526');
    }
}
const theme = ls.get('color');
return (
    <div>
        <style jsx global className='theme'>{`
            body {
                background: ${theme};
            }
        `}</style>
        <label htmlFor='dark'>Dark theme</label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='dark' id='' onClick={set} />
    </div>
);
```

}

```
export default theme;
```

Answer (score 0):

put the style tag in constant variable and the error will go...

wrong --->

```
<div>
    <style jsx global className='theme'>{`
        body {
            background: ${theme};
        }
    `}</style>
    <label htmlFor='dark'>Dark theme</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='dark' id='' onClick={set} />
</div>
```

correct --->

```
const style = (<style jsx global className='theme'>{`
        body {
            background: ${theme};
        }
    `}</style>)
<div>
    {style}
    <label htmlFor='dark'>Dark theme</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='dark' id='' onClick={set} />
</div>
```

error was solved when i started using it inside in a variable